# UPDATE нескольких строк с разным условием

Tags: php, mysql

В таблицу наличия товара необходимо равномерно записывать (UPDATE) количество проданного товара. Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом?

Есть таблица поступления товара:

```
CREATE TABLE `Shop_products` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `amount` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `sold` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Добавляем строки, где `amount` - количество поступившего товара

```
INSERT INTO `Shop_products`(`id`,`name`,`amount`,`sold`) VALUES (1,'Кровать',1,0),
(2,'Кровать',2,0),
(3,'Стол',2,0),
(4,'Кровать',3,0);
```

Теперь нам нужно равномерно списывать товар по мере его продажи и результат заносить в поле `sold`. Например, если купили 1 кровать, то проблем не возникнет. А если купили сразу 4 кровати?

Мы должны списать 1 кровать из строчки `id=1`, 2 кровати из `id=2` и 1 кровать из `id=4`

Можно ли одним запросом так списать товар или только при помощи цикла на PHP?

Comment: А чем отличаются друг от друга группы кроватей? Если бы группа была лишь одна, проблемы бы не возникло

Comment: Отличаются, например датами поставок или ценой закупки, которые нужны для построения отчетов.

Comment: Одним UPDATE-ом не получится, но можно написать хранимку. Точнее не подскажу, надо копать документацию по циклам и курсорам

Comment: наверное можно с CASE разрулить одним запросом, но запрос всё равно с циклом придётся составлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неверный подход к учету. В зависимости от учетной политики методы списания МПЗ могут быть разными. Это может быть и FIFO и по средней (lifo c 2008 в РФ не применяется). Кроме того следует учитывать объективную реальность, когда возможны списания задним числом и просто отмена списания.

Партионный учет реализуется формированием записей: своей на каждое движение. Расчет суммы списания выполняется по соответствующему учетной политике методу.

Пример.

```
Кровать 10 100*10
Кровать  4 120*4
Кровать  7 110*7
```

расход 13 позиций по ФИФО:

```
Кровать -13 -(100*10+120*3)=-1360
```

расход 13 позиций по средней:

```
Кровать -13 -((100*10+120*4+110*7)/21)*13=-1392,86
```

При каждом следующем расходе необходимо учитывать соответствующим образом для каждого метода списания и приходы и расходы:

ФИФО. Берем все приходы и расходы до текущего расхода, итерируем вычитая количества пока не закроем все расходы, останутся не списанные приходы. В итоге будет так:

```
Кровать -3 -(120*1+110*2)=-340
```

По средней. Здесь проще: остаток по сумме делим на остаток по количеству - получаем цену, списываем по ней:

```
Кровать -3 -((100*10+120*4+110*7-1392,86)/(21-13))*3=-321,43
```

N.B. При списании по количеству в ноль, сумма также списывается в ноль, таким образом учитываются ошибки округления.

При необходимости списания задним числом придется пересчитывать все партии, которые пойдут после таких движений.

Такой метод учета избавит не только от необходимости делать все одним update'ом, но и проблем которые могут возникнуть в дальнейшем, в частности "еще одного апдейта чтоб отменить списание". Кроме того, всегда можно просто узнать остаток как по сумме так и по количеству. И самое главное - всегда есть история всех движений.

В больших (по обороту) системах расчет партий может быть довольно затратным по времени или списания задним числом могут привести к тому, что расчет суммы списания для текущего расхода быстро сделать нельзя, а продавать надо - тогда добавляется еще один "регистр" только с количественными данными, а расчет сумм списания выполняется отдельно - регламентом (в партиях добавляется точка актуальности и т.д.).

Разрезов у одного товара может несколько: характеристики (размер, цвет), номер ГТД, серийные номера... При пересортице могут быть серьезные проблемы в учете, их необходимо решать как можно быстрее и история движений сильно в этом помогает.

Comment: Согласен, от update'ов можно уйти, но количество операций не меняется. В данном случае у нас добавятся insert'ы, та самая история операций. Я говорю сейчас про FIFO (так как нужен этот метод списания). Но тогда при каждом списании нужно будет пересчитывать всю историю по товарам, чтобы узнать по какой цене их списывать. Или есть более быстрое решение? Рассматриваем небольшую (по обороту) систему.

Comment: Всю историю пересчитывать не надо. В расчете участвуют только те партии, которые еще не списаны.  Во-первых, история не такая уж и большая даже тысяча строк - это немного (по факту будут десятки). Во-вторых, если для каждого списания хранить партию, из которой расходуем, то получить оставшиеся партии (в наличии) можно одним запросом, например, так: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53339/2

Comment: Да, вы правильно заметили, по факту таблицы будут примерно одинаковыми, с заменой update на insert. Однако, подход совершенно другой: приход не зависит от расхода, расходов может быть несколько на одну партию, пересчитать расходы с определенной даты не представляет труда. fifo меняется на среднюю просто заменой одного запроса на другой, структура останется той же...

Comment: Мы храним в таблице движения всю историю по товарам: (+) поступление или возврат, (-) списание. В целом логика понятна. Действительно все просто можно рассчитать по любому методу (fifo, среднее). Несколько вопросов, если позволите: 1. История получится очень большой или мы ее очищаем когда партия закрыта? 2. Обязательно ли хранить стоимость закупки товара в истории, мы же всегда ее можем получить из таблицы прихода?

Comment: 3. Можно же оптимизировать историю записывая в нее только связи между поступлением и списанием. Для расчета оставшихся партий количество и стоимость мы берем из таблицы поступлений, вычитаем количество из таблицы списаний согласно истории в которой знаем сколько и из какой партии списано и т.д. Таким образом таблица истории уменьшается в разы. Такой вариант неприемлем?

Comment: 1. базы данных нормально работают с большими таблицами, десятки миллионов записей - это немного.
2. Это лишние join'ы. Одна таблица будет быстрее.
3. Важнее тут не размер таблиц, а удобство и скорость работы с ними. Скорость зависит от простоты запроса, размеров выборки, а не размеров всей таблицы.

Comment: Кроме того, дело не ограничивается только приходами и только расходами. Это могут быть и возвраты, и списания и комплектация, и производство, и комиссия и т.д. - несколько видов сущностей (задачи разные бывают, да, у вас может быть проще), которые могут храниться в разных таблицах, а движения свои писать в одну таблицу.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно это делать одним запросом.

Выполнить несколько запросов в цикле никакой проблемы не представляет, а попытки найти какой-то "хак" могут привести к очень неприятным последствиям.

В частности, попытка заменить запрос на обновление запросом на вставку в один прекрасный момент приведет к потере целостности данных, когда один из обновляемых запросом товаров будет удален, а наш запрос на вставку добавит его снова.

В принципе извратиться можно, и сделать UPDATE запрос с CASE. Это будет работать, примеров в сети навалом. Но в 99% случаев овчинка выделки не стоит. Начинающие пользователи обычно рвутся оптимизировать без всякой причины, и всегда делают не то что нужно. Без наличия определенного опыта и без наличия конкретной, реальной проблемы, лучше вообще не заниматься оптимизацией. В большинстве случаев такая попытка не даст никакого прироста эффективности, но внесет в код новые проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вот хак :-)

```sql
INSERT INTO `Shop_products` 
  ( `id`, `amount`, `name`, `sold` ) 
VALUES -- нужно указать name и sold, т.к. для них нет дефолтов
  ( 1, 1, '', 0 ),
  ( 2, 2, '', 0 ),
  ( 4, 1, '', 0 )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `amount` = `amount` - VALUES(`amount`);
```

Обратите внимание: здесь мы в `VALUES` указываем изменения поля `amount`, а не новое количество. Ну и, само собой, должны быть уверены в том, что указаны `id` действительно существующих товаров, иначе что-то лишнее насоздаётся...